# jpa map a composite object to only one table

Tags: java, jpa, orm

With the hope that I won't repeat the question (I really didn't know how to search better):

I have a java Location class with the following fields: name, description, country, gps_coord, added_by

The gps_coord is a class with gps_lat and gps_long memebers.

I want to map the Location class to a database table like this:

name, description, country, gps_lat, gps_long, added_by

How can I map the Location class bearing in mind that the class has a gps_coord class object and the table has the actual members?

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate the `GpsCoord` class as `@Embeddable` and annotate the `gps_coord` attribute in your `Location` class as `@Embedded`.

Mapped like this, the attributes of the embedded class are stored in the same table along with the attributes of the owning class. The DB is oblivious of your `GpsCoord` class. When the row is read, the persistence provider will reconstruct the embedded object.

Take a look at [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) for reference.